# Is it possible to calculate logarithmic return for short position?

Tags: programming, log-returns, short-selling

In the book *"Python for Algorithmic Trading"* by Yves Hilpisch,

it calculates the logarithmic return by summing up all the log values.

When calculates the profit for **long** position: log(current_price/past_price)

When calculates the profit for **short** position: -1*log(current_price/past_price)

And summing up all these log values.

Is the above logic correct for calculating the profit for **short** position?

---

In Python code, it's something like this: (`data` is Pandas `Dataframe`. So, `shift(1)` means just the last price.)

```
# (I shortened the code a bit, but the logic is the same.)
if long:
    data['returns'] = np.log(data['price']/data['price].shift(1))

elif short: 
    data['returns'] = np.log(data['price']/data['price].shift(1)) * (-1)

# final return 
data['returns'].sum()
# plotting
data['returns'].dropna().cumsum().apply(np.exp).plot()
```

the logic for the long position is okay, but... that of the **short** position is not correct, I think.

(I also read [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/34332/59321) which seems correct, and still don't know why the above logic is correct.)

P.S.
Let's say I shorted a stock with **\$10** when it's \$100 and now it's \$20. Then my asset would be **\$18** (80% profit).
But, the above equation says my asset becomes **\$50** ->This is the point I don't understand.

Comment: Yes it is correct. Keep in mind that $(-1) \times \ln \frac{p_t}{p_{t-1}} = \ln \frac{p_{t-1}}{p_t}$. So the two formulas are giving the same result.

Comment: @noob2 Thanks. But the two formulas are not supposed to be the same, aren't they? For example, let's say I short a stock when it's 100USD and the next day it becomes 20USD. Then I earn 80% profit, not 400%. If we follow the above equation, I should get 400% profit(my asset becomes 5 times larger), which makes no sense, doesn't it?

Comment: 80% is the arithmetic return, not the logarithmic return.

Comment: @noob2 yes, but, whatever kind of return we use, our asset should be the same. We use logarithmic return because it has many advantages, but it doesn't change our final asset. So you're saying my asset becomes 5 times larger in the above example I commented? (that is not possible as far as I know)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the differences?

You can check out logarithmic properties in [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/64041/54838). Specifically,

> Reason 2: The log difference is independent of the direction of change

If you code it, you see that the logarithmic return for $$ -1*log(p_1/p_0) = log(p_0/p_1)$$

```
p0 = 100
p1 = 101
retPos = p1/p0-1
retNeg = 1-p1/p0
retLogPos = log(p1/p0)
retLogNeg = log(p0/p1)
retNegSE = -1*retLogPos
println("Positive Return = $retPos")
println("Positive Log Return = $retLogPos")
println("Negative Return = $retNeg")
println("Negative Log Return = $retLogNeg")
println("Negative Log Return Alternative = $retNegSE")
```

[image]

Edit: Log return do NOT equal normal returns as [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/22778/54838) explains.
The relationship between normal and log returns is
$$(normal return) = exp(log return)-1$$

```
p0 = 100
p1 = 20
retPos = p1/p0-1
retNeg = 1-p1/p0
retLogPos = log(p1/p0)
retLogNeg = log(p0/p1)
retNegSE = -1*retLogPos
println("Positive Return = $retPos")
println("Positive Log Return = $retLogPos")
println("Negative Return = $retNeg")
println("Negative Log Return = $retLogNeg")
println("Negative Log Return Alternative = $retNegSE")
println("Order doesnt matter for log: $(retLogNeg == retNegSE)")
println("Normal return from Log = $(1- exp(-retLogNeg))")
```

[image]

If you get small differences, this is not a computational error but explained by floating point math:
[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)
[Rounding in Python](https://kfolds.com/rounding-in-python-when-arithmetic-isnt-quite-right-11a79a30390a)
[Is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

In my initial example I made a silly mistake. I used $p0/p1-1$ instead of $1-p1/p0$ which equals $(p0-p1)/p0$. It does not affect the log return computation but the arithmetic return itself. Apologies for the confusion. I need to look more properly before answering - thanks for teaching me a lesson!

The reason I used -retLogNeg is that [A = P e^rt](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/compound-interest/continuously-compounded-interest.php) = `$100 * e^-1.6094379124341003 = $20` (start value to get today's value). Technically, this assumes that the short sell is a liability that must be paid back at a future date. If it drops to zero, your liability vanishes and you get 100% return as you correctly stated.

The change in log is not a percentage per se, it approximates it for small changes (returns) as shown in my initial link.

Comment: Apologies, did not want to duplicate @noob's work. I did not see the post without refreshing the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just let me describe my real question once again: Does the negative return 4.0 in your code mean that it's the return we get when we short a stock that was 100USD and now 20USD? (As far as I know, it should be 0.8, not 4.0)

Comment: You sell at 100 and need to pay back only 20 (excluding fees). What is your return if you pay 20 and sell at 100? See [also](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/20739/54838).

Comment: I think I get your point, but let's think about the real situation: Let's say my start asset is \$10. If I bought a stock at \$20 and sell at \$100, then of course my return would be 4.0(my asset becomes \$50). But, when we short, we sell first, so I can sell only a limited amount, isn't it? So, If I short a stock when its price was \$100 and now \$20, then my asset would be \$18. As far as I know, in short-selling, the return cannot be larger than 100% (if no leverage). Did I get something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: (The question I commented in the link you gave) If we just ignore fees, then the return becomes log(entryprice/exitprice). If exitprice = (1/100)*entryprice, then it's log(100). Does this possible in short-selling?

Comment: Why not? You simply borrow shares to sell them. [Investing answers](https://investinganswers.com/dictionary/s/short-selling) has  another example where you gain 25% (500 of 2000 or 2500/2000-1). I am not sure what else to say, so I will leave it to someone to comment further.  The author himself is renowned, all resources I referenced state the same and it really is just percent calc, which is why I opted to close that question.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for helping a newbie. The example in the Investing answers you linked has no problem at all. Yeah it's just simple calc and I understand the math part, but just don't understand how initial asset X can become greater than 2*X by short-selling. Again, thank you very much, and if somebody sees this, please feel free to comment.